# JPA/ Hibernate query child property

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I use the single table strategy (with discriminator) to use inheritance

UML schema => http://yuml.me/67acf6a6

I would like to fetch all the orders of a customer with all the associations related (cars, books and tvs). Do you know how to achieve this without breaking the model classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer{
  private Date birthDate;
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @OrderBy("order")
  private List<? extends Order> orders;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Order{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerID")
    private Customer customer;
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("book")
public class BookOrder extends Order {

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
  private Set<Book> books;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("car")
public class CarOrder extends Order {

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name="car_id")
  private Set<Car> cars;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("tv")
public class TvOrder extends Order {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name="tv_id")
  private Set<Tv> tvs; 
}
```

If I'm doing in HQL

```
select cutomer from customer customer
inner join fetch customer.orders order
left join fetch order.cars
left join fetch order.books
left join fetch order.tvs
```

I'm getting the error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: cars,
```

It makes sense in the abstract class Order this field doesnt exist.

Do you know how i can achieve this ? what is the recommendation of hibernate in this case ?

My goal is to simple a simple query and to fetch everything.

Comment: Your query uses a comma instead of a dot, and doesn't assign an alias to the order. Is that the real HQL? That said, you can't fetch multiple bags, so even if such a query is possible, it probably won't work unless your collections are Sets.

Comment: Sorry i corrected. I change with sets, but i how achieve this

Comment: You still don't have an alias. It should be `inner join fetch customer.orders orders ...`

Comment: Yes i corrected. i just create an example from scratch. But the main idea is explained in my sample code and diagram.

Comment: Here is my guess. This might be happening because the property you are trying to join is not present in the parent Order class. Instead all the three properties are there in their respective child classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following query

```
select c from customer c
join fetch c.orders
```

then you retrieve all the customers with any types of the orders (cars | books | tvs). Those orders are polymorphic, if do `instanceof` for each Customer.orders element you can determine what type of order element is.

Comment: Nop, if im doing like this i going to use the lazy loading. Its not optimal. i want to fetch the related associations (cars, books, tvs) declare in LAZY in one or two times.

Comment: Are you sure it fetched it lazily? We use join fetch here, it pre-fetch the collection, which is polymorphic in our case.

Comment: Im talking about the child associations (BookOrder.books, CarOrder.cars, TvOrder.tv) the collection is declared as LAZY, it will not be fetch.
I try to find a way to fetch everything, i got some solutions but it break the models.

The only solution i got, is to do some separate query to fetch every child association. But is not really optimized.